# Git clone fails if you have a custom SSH Port

Tags: linux, ssh, rocky-os

I have changed the SSH Port on my Rocky Linux 9.1 machine.As a result `git clone` and `git pull` hangs. There is no error even with `verbose` .

`git clone git@github.com:videojs/video.js.git`

`cat /root/.ssh/config`

```
Host github.com
Hostname github.com
Port 22
```

I have also tried the following config but its not working

```
Host github.com
Hostname ssh.github.com
Port 443
User git
```

**Edit**

```
ssh -vvT git@github.com
```

```
OpenSSH_8.7p1, OpenSSL 3.0.1 14 Dec 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host github.com originally github.com
debug2: match not found
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host github.com originally github.com
debug2: match found
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.255.113] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-2fb663a1
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-2fb663a1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
```

Comment: Changing the ssh port of your ssh server should be completely unrelated to not being able to open a `git+shh` connection as a client to github. Your ssh server is never involved in this. You mush have changed something else. Take `git` out of the equation and try `ssh -vvT git@github.com`. It should answer with `Hi <your github account here>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`, provided that you have a valid ssh key. If it doesn't reply with that, then check the verbose output and look for the cause.

Comment: @cornuz I have added output of `ssh -vvT git@github.com` . Thanks for the quick response

Comment: That's all you get? After that you should get `debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received`, followed by authentication attempts.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but if you google for `SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT hangs`, you get many issues pointing to MTU/fragmentation problems. Check that the MTU of your network interface is not set to some high value. Maybe set it to 576 and try again.

Comment: @cornuz changing the MTU from 1500 to 576 solve the issue but why that is happening because on my other servers mtu is 1500. Does that indicate a hardware problem?

Comment: No I don't think so. I wouldn't even be surprised if it worked again at 1500, but restarting the network service. Other things to check: what else is on that server? A VPN? A firewall? Anything that could interfere with network settings?

Answer (score 0):

I just can give you a single clue because I don't know much about ssh.

On MacBook, Before I modified `Host github.com` to `Host ssh.github.com`, ssh test log was the same as yours. After modification, never the less, `ssh -Tv git@github.com` tested OK, but git still uses port 22.

```
Host ssh.github.com
   User git
   Port 443
   HostName ssh.github.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

```bash
# ssh test ok
ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
"Hi MoeexT! You\'ve successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access."

# ----------------------------------------

# git fetch or push still uses port 22
git fetch -v
"kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by 20.205.243.166 port 22
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."
```

On win10-WSL-ubuntu2204, I didn't change that `Host`, its still OK.

GitHub reference: [Using SSH over the HTTPS port](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port)